# Cannot install node-sass npm module

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sass, npm, nvm

I'm attempting to install the npm module "node-sass" on my Ubuntu 14.04 distro.

When I run

```
node -v
```

I get

> v0.10.32

However, when attempting to install node-sass and harp with this command:

```
sudo npm install -g harp
```

I get the following error:

```html
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:66:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:152:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:95:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:722:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:999:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1167:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:461:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/harp/node_modules/terraform/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! node-sass@0.9.3 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.9.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "harp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin
npm ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/colin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**Note that the error states that my node version is still v0.13.0-pre even though I switched to 0.10.32 with nvm.**

Comment: Sounds like node is not installed in the directory that node-sass is looking for it in. try running ```which node``` i do believe that it should return ```/usr/bin/node```

Comment: Unfortunately you're a little bit late to the party since I've actually replaced my computer and removed Ubuntu in favor of OSX, but I'm nearly positive that `which node` returned `/usr/local/bin/node`.

Comment: me too getting similar error. anybody any update?

Answer (score 1):

Question is 3 years old, yet I have recently encountered same problem on osx trying to install `harp` and found no solution elsewhere.

After several attempts managed to solve the problem with `--unsafe-perm` modifier, like follow:
`sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm harp`

Install went successful and everything works, hope that helps :)